# Algorithm for route mapping between Customer and Driver - ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API where Customer and Driver can create their travelling route. For example, a Customer can create a route for their journey from their house to their company at 9am every morning. And a Driver can create a route that they want to drive, for instance, from their house to their workplace. One Customer/Driver can have many routes created and saved.

The problem here is to **map routes between Customer and Driver** such that Driver can drive a customer on the Customer's route and that route should **match** (or **nearby**) the Driver's saved routes. And the mapping should be **optimized** for the Driver so that the Driver can have multiple suitable Customers and distance between different customer's routes should be as small as possible.

I am trying to find a suitable algorithm which can be implemented using C# .NET 6. Do you have any idea or suggestion about the algorithm or the keyword to be searched?

Thank you so much.